# Why should I set the source device with < > when using pv?

Tags: syntax, pv

I have a question out of curiosity ;-)

I find that I could accomplish cloning a disk with the command `pv` instead of `dd` too.

For that I used what I found in the internet
`pv < /dev/sda1 > /dev/sdb1`.

Why must I use the `<` operator here?

From the man pages I would assume that the right command would be
`pv /dev/sda1 > /dev/sdb1`

Answer (score 3):

Both approaches work: if `pv` is given files to read from as arguments, it reads from them, otherwise it reads from its standard input.

```
pv /dev/sda1 > /dev/sdb1
```

relies on the former,

```
pv < /dev/sda1 > /dev/sdb1
```

on the latter.

Some people might prefer the latter because it provides more confidence that `/dev/sda1` isn’t going to be written to, but I’m not sure that’s guaranteed on all platforms.

Comment: The former might allow pv to estimate the size better, I'd think.

Comment: Note: `pv < /dev/sda > /dev/null` in my Debian is smart enough to determine the size of `sda`. I understand the issue with `cat /dev/sda | pv`. On the other hand `wc -c < regular_file` works instantly and `wc -c < /dev/sda` begins *reading and counting*; but so does `wc -c /dev/sda`. In any case `pv -d "$(pidof wc)"` can show me ETA. `pv` is aware of block devices and quite smart with them; e.g. if the input size cannot be calculated and the output is a block device, then the size of the block device will be used to calculate progress. This applies to `pv /dev/urandom >/dev/sdx` as well.

Comment: @muru it turns out `pv` finds the size just fine with `<` (the fd points to the device). That’s only an issue with pipes.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, on systems like Linux, `stat()` or `fstat()` which `wc` use report 0 for the size instead of the size of the underlying storage, while `lseek()` works. I support `pv` is smart enough to resort to `lseek()` for block devices. Note that in any case, both `wc` or `pv` need to use `lseek()` when reading from stdin to know the current position within he file (they don't report/transfer the size of the full file but how much can be read from stdin). `wc` does but `pv` doesn't (at least not version 1.6.6) which is actually a bug.